# Unable to download via wget

Tags: git, wget, rhel7

I am trying to download git via wget on a RHEL 7.5 box. When i open it in a browser, the file downloads. However when I try when, it hangs indefinitely.

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.0.0.tar.gz
--2020-02-11 22:55:48--  https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.0.0.tar.gz
Resolving mirrors.edge.kernel.org (mirrors.edge.kernel.org)... 147.75.197.195, 2604:1380:1:3600::1
Connecting to mirrors.edge.kernel.org (mirrors.edge.kernel.org)|147.75.197.195|:443... connected.
```

I will appreciate pointers on this.

Comment: why you do not install `git` via `yum`?

Comment: Also why you do not use the official git source repo? https://github.com/git/git

Comment: @RomeoNinov can you please paste a command to grab got from there? When I try with wget it hangs, it doesn’t seem like the hit release page lends itself to be downloaded via wget

Comment: @RomeoNinov I need v2.* and RHEL’s yum installs v. 1.83

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. This is probably better asked at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it downloads via the browser, you can try adding the "-U" flag to the wget command. Copy the browser's user-agent string and use that in wget as the value for the "-U" option.

Also, if that does not work, add the "-v" flag to curl, and paste the output here, so that someone can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I got same "stuck" message on "connected" on my Windows 10 machine in "cmder" program.

HTTP worked, but HTTPS didn't.

I ended up using a different version which worked.

[Bad version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/): GNU Wget 1.11.4

[Good version](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/): GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on mingw32.